# Managing Loading State in React Apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about how to manage state in a React apps. What I have been accustomed to doing is something like this - some of this is pseudocode:

```
Home.js

const LOADING_TIMEOUT_CONSTANT = 1000
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home(){
  const [loaded, isLoaded] = useState(false);
  const results = getData();

  useEffect(()=> {
    // wait for results to fetch from server
    setTimeout(() => {
      isLoaded(true)
    }, LOADING_TIMEOUT_CONSTANT)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {!loaded ? <p>Loading ....</p> : <p>Homepage Content Here</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This however, seems a bit clunky to me and I'm not clear on best practices. Is this the standard, or are there other ways to manage this type of conditional display based on loading states or just any asynchronous fetching?

Thanks!

Tried searching stackoverflow, looking up youtube videos, searching reddit, etc. but I'm more looking into what the overall standard is for react developers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there isn't a best practice to things in developers world, but instead of relying on a `setTimeout()`, I tend to manually assign states using `try..catch..finally` like:

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  const getSomething = async() => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      //fetch code
    } catch (error) {
      //error handler
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  getSomething();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes so that loading state can be updated when getData request completes.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home(){
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [results, setResults] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        // Assuming getData is an async function
        const data = await getData();
        setResults(data); // Store the fetched data in state
        setLoaded(true); // Update loading state after data is fetched
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        setLoaded(true); // Ensure loading state is updated even if fetching fails
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once on mount

  return (
    <div>
      {!loaded ? <p>Loading ....</p> : <p>Homepage Content Here</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways could be using promises(.then() and .catch())

```
 fetch('https://your-url.com',options)
.then(res => setResults(res.data))
.then(() => setLoading(true))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

In this way, the loading state will always be updated after the fetching is done. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

This is other ways to manage this type of condition

```
if(!loaded){
return (
    <div>
      <p>Loading ....</p>
    </div>
  )
}
return (
    <div>
      <p>Homepage Content Here</p>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the nice and easy-to-learn conventions you could follow is using `React Query` with `Axios` for asynchronous data fetching:

For example (more details can be found [here](https://www.copycat.dev/blog/react-query/)):

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export default function Repositories() {
  const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(["repo"], () =>
    axios
      .get("https://api.github.com/users/eunit99/repos")
      .then((res) => res.data)
  );
 
  if (isLoading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;
  return (
    <>
      {data}
    </>
  )
};
```

> `React Query` basically gives you the `useQuery` hook that returns a
> handful of objects such as `isLoading, data, error, refetch`, etc.
> These objects will help you check different states and render output
> accordingly.
>
> `Axios` helps you to fetch/send data using promises.

To learn about more advanced usage of these tools, check out their docs at the links below:

- [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest)

Comment: You're over-complicating the answer by suggesting the OP to start looking into `React-Query`, his question relates to simple state management and React-query is a whole different beast of it's own.